# C# Parse XML to different lists

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xamarin.forms

I have a problem.
In my Xamarin Forms app I do a webcall to my webpage, where I collect XML to use in the app. I parse the XML to 3 different Lists.

1. Albums
2. Images
3. Formats

Now here is what my xml looks like:

```
<Data>
    <Albums>
        <Album>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
        </Album>
        <Album>
            <Image></Image>
            <Image></Image>
        </Album>
    </Albums>
    <Images>
        <Image></Image>
        <Image></Image>
        <Image></Image>
        <Image></Image>
    </Images>
    <Formats>
        <Format></Format>
        <Format></Format>
    </Formats>
</Data>
```

After parsing it, the wanted result is:

```
lstAlbums.Count = 2
lstImages.Count = 4
lstFormats.Count = 2
```

But apparently it counts all the `<>` tags in the full xml, so `lstImages` has a count of 9, because 5 from the albums and 4 from the `<Images>`

Here is my c# code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlString))
{
    doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
}

//Check if xml has any elements 
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlString) && doc.Root.Elements().Any())
{
    App.lstAlbums = doc.Descendants("Albums").Descendants("Album").Select(d =>
    new Album
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(d.Element("Id").Value),
        Name = d.Element("Name").Value,
        Images = doc.Descendants("Album").Descendants("Image").Select(a =>
            new myImage
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(a.Element("Id").Value),
                Name = a.Element("Name").Value,
                Size = a.Element("Size").Value,
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(a.Element("Price").Value)
            }).ToList(),
        Prijs = Convert.ToDecimal(d.Element("Price").Value)
    }).ToList();

    App.lstImages = doc.Descendants("Images").Descendants("Image").Select(e =>
    new myImage
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Element("Id").Value),
        Name = e.Element("Name").Value
    }).ToList();

    App.lstFormats = doc.Descendants("Formats").Descendants("Format").Select(e =>
    new Format
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Element("Id").Value),
        Size = e.Element("Size").Value,
        Price = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Element("Price").Value)
    }).ToList();
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `Descendents` method is recursive; if you only intend to look one level, use `Elements` instead, but frankly this looks like a good fit for `XmlSerializer` instead of manual parsing.

Comment: Can you provide me with an example code for one of my lists, for example Albums?

Comment: I'd deserialise this, manual parsing is just a lot of code that already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frankly, this is a job for `XmlSerializer`. The following should work:

```cs
[XmlRoot("Data")]
public class MyData {
    [XmlArray("Albums")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Album")]
    public List<Album> Albums {get;} = new List<Album>();

    [XmlArray("Images")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Image")]
    public List<string> Images {get;} = new List<string>();

    [XmlArray("Formats")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Format")]
    public List<string> Formats {get;} = new List<string>();
}

public class Album {
    [XmlElement("Image")]
    public List<string> Images {get;} = new List<string>();
}
```

usage:

```cs
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
var obj = (MyData)serializer.Deserialize(source);
```

And if your real xml is more complex: just copy the xml into the clipboard, and edit => paste special => paste xml as classes

(there are also sites/tools that let you convert your xml to c# code, of varying quality - for example https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/, but note that this doesn't do a great job around the arrays etc)

Comment: Okay, I added your code, but it crashes on this line: `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));` with the error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'There was an error reflecting type 'MyApp.Models.MyData'.'`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk and what does the inner-exception say? it is usually pretty chatty about what the problem is

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk also: works fine here - did you perhaps change the accessibility? https://gist.github.com/mgravell/0180b1b46eb4388b3aa733c5aee1afd3

Comment: I think why I get this error. I did a few changes, because your code wasn't complete for my code. I need to add the classes: Image and Format. You already added Album.

Can you please update your code with the following classes, so I can see what I did wrong:
`Album => Id, Name, List<Image> Images --- Image => Id, Name, Price --- Format => Id, Size`

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk like this? https://gist.github.com/mgravell/16ea2d86636e87d82db5a4b55a4d491e

Comment: What happens when I don't get for example a name from a Image in an album? Does it crash, because I think that that is what is happening!?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk no, that's fine. If you're seeing "There was an error reflecting type", them it hasn't even got as far as looking at the data. LOOK AT THE INNER EXCEPTIONS. It will tell you what the problem is. Meaning: `catch` the exception, and in the debugger, look at `ex.Message`, `ex.InnerException.Message`, `ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message`, etc - until you run out of inner exceptions

Comment: Okay, I know what is causing the error. In my Image class, I added imageSource, because foreach image I get the source from my webserver. But apparently the app crashes, because imageSource is not in the XML. I know this, because when I remove that from my class, the app works fine. Any idea how to fix this!?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206940/discussion-between-a-vreeswijk-and-marc-gravell).

Answer (score -1):

Try using xPath.

Something like

```
(IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate("//Albums/Album")
```

and

```
(IEnumerable)doc.XPathEvaluate("//Images/Image")
```

Comment: And how can I assign that to my Lists?

Comment: iterate over the IEnumerable (or select from it).  You'll want to cast each item in the IEnumerable to an XElement (because you have knowledge of what the XML structure is).  Then extract the attributes from the XElement.  XElement has Attribute and Attributes methods.  XmlSerializer could be a better option, but this should be an easy swap for the code you alread have.